# How do I manipulate strong in SRT file in python?

Tags: python, string, text

If I have a SRT file such as this:

```
1
00:00:00672 --> 00:00:05568
This is about

2
00:00:05664 --> 00:00:11175
whatever

3
00:00:11303 --> 00:00:16359
I don't know

4
00:00:16423 --> 00:00:20647
you don't know
```

But there's something wrong with the format because the comma is missing in the timestamp, and it should be like this:

```
1
00:00:00,672 --> 00:00:05,568
This is about

2
00:00:05,664 --> 00:00:11,175
whatever

3
00:00:11,303 --> 00:00:16,359
I don't know

4
00:00:16,423 --> 00:00:20,647
you don't know
```

How can I fix it with python? Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to fix this in a text editor.  Is this a one-time thing, or is this something that's being generated wrong all the time?

Comment: It's waste of time because there's over 100 lines. It's being generated wrong all the time after translation in google translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the start of the format, and assert the last 3 digits.

```
--> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?=\d{3}\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dPI0pT/1)

and replace with the full match and a comma

```
r"\g<0>,"
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0jwXT2)

```
import re
 
regex = r"--> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?=\d{3}\b)"
 
s = ("1\n"
    "00:00:00672 --> 00:00:05568\n"
    "This is about\n\n"
    "2\n"
    "00:00:05664 --> 00:00:11175\n"
    "whatever\n\n"
    "3\n"
    "00:00:11303 --> 00:00:16359\n"
    "I don't know\n\n"
    "4\n"
    "00:00:16423 --> 00:00:20647\n"
    "you don't know")
 
result = re.sub(regex, r"\g<0>,", s)
 
if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
1
00:00:00672 --> 00:00:05,568
This is about

2
00:00:05664 --> 00:00:11,175
whatever

3
00:00:11303 --> 00:00:16,359
I don't know

4
00:00:16423 --> 00:00:20,647
you don't know
```

Comment: This is just an example, if I have over 100 lines, what do I do with the s = part? Thanks

Comment: @saga `s` contains the string with the data you want to change. If you read the data for example from a file, you can read all lines, and afterwards write the content back to a/the file.

Comment: I have a problem with this method, everything works fine besides the LAST timestamp which CAN'T be read properly. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @saga Do you have an example that does not work?  Or can you update this example https://regex101.com/r/dPI0pT/1 ?

Comment: I don't know how to show you an example. The process is after I use your code, I will copy the converted timestamp and text and paste to replace the SRT file content and save it. Then I will use the new replaced file content to create subtitles. But everytime, it can't read the last line or last timestamp, so there's something wrong with the last timestamp so the the subtitle program can read it.

Comment: @saga Do the timestamps always have 3 digits at the end like `647` in `00:00:20647` ? What does the last timestamp look like?

Comment: Yes it does, I created a new post here, not sure if it will help but you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800548/how-to-convert-all-regex-properly?noredirect=1#comment126898715_71800548

Comment: @saga But the replacement works correctly in the regex101 environment right? https://regex101.com/r/0hAxvS/1 I can also not reproduce it with the data in the new posted question.

Comment: Nope, I just tried, the last line couldn't be read even if I use regex 101 env. There's something wrong with the last timestamp so the subtitle program can't read it.

Comment: @saga The demo here works right? https://regex101.com/r/0hAxvS/1 Can you create a reproducible example with your existing data that does not match?

Comment: I create a new blank line at the end manually and it works. I guess it's not because of the timestamp in this case then, it's just the the subtitle can't be the last line in the file somehow....